# Display all webhooks in the current discord server discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command to display every webhook made in the specific guild, I thought this would work:

```
let allwebhooks = "";
  
  message.guilds.cache.forEach(webhook => {
    allwebhooks += `${hook.name}, `;
  });
  let webhookembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#8f82ff")
  .setTitle(`There are ${hook.size} webhooks in: **${message.guild.name}**:`)
  .setDescription(
    `Webhooks: \n **${allwebhooks.slice(
    0,
      allwebhooks.length - 2
    )}**`
    );
    message.channel.send(webhookembed)
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

The second line(one before `forEach`) should be something like this:

```js
message.guild.fetchWebhooks().then(webhooks => {
```

And modify the `forEach` line to the following code:

```js
webhooks.forEach(webhook => {
```

`message` does not have `guilds` property but `guild`.
And `guild` has `fetchWebhooks()` that returns a promise of all webhooks of the guild. So you can do that with `fetchWebhooks()`.

EDIT: append `})` after all the other codes. Otherwise it will throw a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: oh this works! how would you get all the names of them, i tried doing `${webhooks.name}` but it just returns undefined

Comment: try `webhook.name`. `webhooks` is the collection of webhooks and `webhook` is the single webhook.